# What is this lockscreen app?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop

So sometimes when I try to unlock my phone I am greeted with this:
[image]

When I swipe up I am greeted with my regular lockscreen. Why exactly am I seeing this lockscreen? It appears randomly, does not appear every time. I dont have any lockscreen app installed. I am using Android 5.1 with **stock** launcher.

Comment: It's possible, that some launcher installs a custom lock-screen as well. Would you mind adding the launcher you are using to the question?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the Go Launcher locker app.... Just by the four petal clover  ...

Also King root makes a lock screen like that

Comment: Yeah, I did root my phone using King Root, actually.. that must be it.. Thanks.

Comment: @mayankbudhwani Yeah, to get rid of this custom lock screen, disable the option "charging lock screen in kingroot or the purify app. Forgot which one.